# Does cron depend on systemd for starting?

Tags: cron, systemd

I'm learning about cron and systemd to schedule scripts.

Each can be used independently to schedule scripts.

I'm curious to know whether cron depends on systemd to keep itself alive? For example at cron crash or system reboot does systemd manage the cron service startup?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that `cron` is a `systemd` service on current Ubuntu systems. Meaning that `systemd` notices when the `cron` deamon terminates, and manages a restart. For this purpose, there is a `cron.service` file defined in the `/etc/systemd` folder. Is that an answer to your question?

Comment: @Jos yes it is so make it one :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Yes,

in the sense that `cron` is a `systemd` service on current Ubuntu systems. That means that `systemd` notices when the `cron` deamon terminates, and manages a restart. For this purpose, there is a `cron.service` file defined in the `/etc/systemd` folder:

```
[Unit]
Description=Regular background program processing daemon
Documentation=man:cron(8)
After=remote-fs.target nss-user-lookup.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/cron
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f -P $EXTRA_OPTS
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is all the information `systemd` needs to manage the `cron` service: its executable, what to do when the service needs to be killed, when to restart it, its dependencies on other services, etc.